# Best way to save a dictionary which contains non-ASCII characters in Datastore with Python ndb

Tags: python, python-2.7, non-ascii-characters, datastore, ndb

I have this dict: `{'ª': 'a'}` and want to save it to ndb object.

The superscript `ª` is a non-ASCII character.

Initially I was saving the mapping as a json dump string. I had this class:

```
class MyClass:
  mapping = ndb.TextProperty()
```

And saving was doing something like:

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.mapping = json.dumps({'ª': 'a'})
```

This was raising an error, because `dumps` (in Python 2.7) doesn't support non-ASCII chars.

So, I tried to define different model:

```
class MyClass:
  mapping = ndb.JsonProperty()
```

and save like this:

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.mapping = {'ª': 'a'}
obj.put()
```

This fails during `obj.put()` with the following error:

```
utf8 codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I'm interested in some general advise around best practices how to save non-ASCII dicts in Datastore using Python 2 and ndb.

I am thinking about trying pickle/cPickle, but am a bit reluctant because here we store user provided data, so using pickle might not be very secure.

Comment: As a first step, I'd probably ensure that any `str` keys or values are converted to `unicode` instances, ideally at the boundary of your system.  JSONProperty ought to work fine with such values. It's much easier to work with non-ASCII values in Python2 if you decode to `unicode` when they are received as requests and  encode as `str` when they are output as responses.

Comment: @snakecharmerb the conversion to unicode fails too:

>>> unicode('ª')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You need to specify the encoding `unicode('ª', 'utf8')`

Comment: thanks a lot @snakecharmerb, that was very helpful! 

In my actual code I was reading from a .csv file and `utf8` didn't really work, but it worked when I switched to `latin1`. I'm just not sure which encoding to use to ensure best support for different encodings. Any idea if there is some safe choice? If I just leave this to latin1, I won't really know why exactly it has to be latin1 and whether it would work for some different non-ascii chars in the future (which would be out of latin1 char set).

Comment: If possible I'd use UTF-8 and specify that the csvs be encoded as UTF-8.  If you don't control the encoding of the files there are packages like charset-normalizer or chardet that can guess the encoding.